# Why wasn't Kochikame translated into English? (Official translation and scanlation as well)

Tags: kochikame

The question above says everything. Why wasn't Kochikame translated into English in any form?

Comment: Maybe you can include some context.

Comment: I can only speculate, but part of it may be cultural, being steeped in Japanese idiosyncrasies might have made it unappealing to foreign companies and another may be how dated it is, its premise of being set at the time of its publication made it hip for its time but is now like watching early Simpsons making Blockbuster jokes and referencing the Waltons. In addition it isn't unique in its absence in the west, a quick scan of the longest running manga will reveal many popular local franchises virtually unheard of abroad. Works like Sazae-san, Dokaben, Cooking Papa, Minami no Teio, etc.